# Error when compiling a DirectX9, program says in cannot find d3dx.lib

Tags: c++, directx

I have already placed d3d.lib and d3dx.lib in additional dependencies, and added the paths to the VC++ directories include and lib Directories, but I am still getting this error.

I have even gone as far as to move the Include and lib flies from the SDK into the include and lib files of VS 2010.

Comment: Add `#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx.lib")` to the top of the main source file and try compiling it.

Comment: Okay, where is "d3dx.lib" located? Hardcode the entire path like this (use forward slashes) `#pragma comment(lib, "c:/mypath/d3dx.lib")`

Comment: Still not working, i changed all of the slashes and everything, ahhh why does this not work, this always happens when i get into Direct X

Comment: "I have even gone as far as to move the Include and lib flies from the SDK into the include and lib files of VS 2010."  This is not a good idea.

Comment: Triple check your include and library paths, then try building on the command line with `/verbosity:diagnostic` and look at exactly how MSBuild is invoking the compiler.

Comment: Forgive me if that is stupid, but are you sure you need to add d3dx.lib, and not d3dx9.lib?

Answer (score 1):

For D3D9, you want to link against d3d9.lib and d3dx9.lib, not d3d.lib and d3dx.lib. There are also d3d10.lib, d3d10_1.lib, d3d11.lib, d3dx10.lib and d3dx11.lib corresponding to other D3D versions.